# boost multiarray of user defined class object

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I need to describe a boost multiarray of two dimensions of object class that is myclass. Is it possible? or only is possible to define multiarray with standard types as int, double, etc.

Comment: can't you write boost::multi_array<myclass, 2>?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike 'native' C++ arrays, boost multi-arrays have value semantics.

Your element type is required to be copyable, because `multi_array` promises to be copyable:

> #### `multi_array`
>
> ...
>
> **Model Of.***  `MultiArray`, `CopyConstructible`. Depending on the element type, it may also model `EqualityComparable` and `LessThanComparable`.

Compare the following:

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

using Arr = boost::multi_array<int, 3>;

struct Ok { };
struct NotOk : boost::noncopyable { };

int main()
{
    boost::multi_array<int,   3> arr1(boost::extents[7][6][3]); // ok
    boost::multi_array<Ok,    3> arr2(boost::extents[7][6][3]); // ok
    boost::multi_array<NotOk, 3> arr3(boost::extents[7][6][3]); // COMPILE ERROR
}
```

See it **[On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1642f712fad6064)**

Comment: This is not 100% correct, at least nowadays. It is ok to declare and use an array of non-copyable objects as long as you don't copy the array itself. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b0b3e0a4eb2829f . I think this is the correct way most containers should behave (for the most part, the operations enabled in the container should be the operations allowed on the element). https://godbolt.org/z/We5b3br84

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a class template. It was designed to replace std::vector nesting, and use less memory. `boost::multi_array<myclass, 2>`, creates a two-dimensional array of myclass.

Comment: Yes I have try to define

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have try with

```
typedef boost::multi_array<Pixel, 2> pixel_2d_t;
```

(Pixel is my class) and defining Pixel in a header file Pixel.h

```
class Pixel:
    public IRDetectorComponent<Pixel>::Type
    ,public det::IRPositionable<Pixel>
    {
    public:

        static const char* const kComponentName;

        static const char* const kComponentId;
        /**
         *   Pixel Status definition
         */
        enum Status {
          eGood = 0,
          eBadCalibration = 1,
          eUnknown
        };
```

...
...

But I obtain as error

/home/lperal/jemeuso/jape/External/boost/1_55_0/include/boost/multi_array/base.hpp:139:25: error: arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type
      'irdet::CCD::Pixel'
    TPtr newbase = base + idx * strides[0];

Being CCD.h the class where I have defined the multiarray into the irdet namespace.